# kohana 3.2 how to enable imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, kohana-3

imagemagick is installed on my system (aptitude says so...)

I downloaded a kohana-image-driver ([here](https://github.com/tmihalik/kohana-imagemagick-driver)) and put it into the kohana module folder.

Then I added in my bootstrap.php, in the Kohana::modules array:

```
'kohana-imagemagick-driver'    => MODPATH.'kohana-imagemagick-driver',
```

In a controller, I'm trying to call it with:

```
$image = new Kohana_Image_Imagick($path . $filename);
```

But I get this error:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Imagick is not installed, or the extension is not loaded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you dont have the PHP imagick extension installed. You can install that extension like so (on debian systems):

```
apt-get install php5-imagick
```

---

Why are you using a 3rd party module when the imagemagick driver exists in 3.2?

There's a couple of ways enable the imagemagick driver in Kohana 3.2:

In your bootstrap.php, add:

```
Image::$default_driver = 'imagick';
```

OR, pass in the driver sting as an argument for the factory method

```
Image::factory($file, 'imagick');
```

OR, extend the image class:
EG, in file: application/classes/image.php

```
abstract class Image extends Kohana_Image {

  public static $default_driver = 'imagick';
}
```

Comment: I thought imagemagick was automatically inluded with the php5 package... and didn't know you don't need the driver in Kohana 3.2...
Now it's working, but I get this error: Call to undefined method Imagick::getImageAlphaChannel() ... :-/

Comment: Not sure exactly, you might need an earlier version, see here: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9654/kohana-3.2-image-imagick-driver/p1